# Remove entries ending in 'X' from column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a column of film titles. Some of these titles include the release date of the film (e.g. 'Toy Story (1995)'), but some do not. I want to delete the entries which DO NOT have a date. I tried to do this by saying "If the last character is not ')', make the entire entry blank." I tried the following code - it didn't give me an error, but it didn't work either:

```py
for i in df['title']:
   if i[-1] != ')':
      i = ''
```

For instance, a shorted dataframe might be:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'title': ['Toy Story (1995)', 'The Matrix (1999)', 'Jumanji', 'Interstellar (2014)']})
```

Comment: Would you please add some representative data to your question? Need to know the date formats, for instance.

Comment: Provide samples from data specifying the ones which come under example having release date and example not having release date. If they have many patterns, provide as many patterns in the examples as possible. Otherwise, people will find it difficult to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If format of date is just year in brackets at the end of movie title, then try:

```
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'movie':['Toy Story (1995)','Toy Story (no date)','Oddyssey 2000', 'Fort 6600', 'The Matrix (1999)', 'Jumanji', 'Interstellar (2014)']})
```

`df`:

```
                 movie
0     Toy Story (1995)
1  Toy Story (no date)
2        Oddyssey 2000
3            Fort 6600
4    The Matrix (1999)
5              Jumanji
6  Interstellar (2014)
```

Using regular expression:

```
df[df.movie.apply(lambda x: bool(re.search('\([1-2][0-9]{3}\)$', x)))]
```

result:

```
                 movie
0     Toy Story (1995)
4    The Matrix (1999)
6  Interstellar (2014)
```

Numbers that are not years or are not in brackets will not be included in the result. I assumed year must begin with 1 or 2.

Comment: This works as expected if I create a new dataframe, but when I apply it on my imported one, for some reason it doesn't seem to do anything (this is the case with most other suggestions).

Comment: What is the name of Your dataframe, and column name containing movie titles,  maybe there is some kind of name conflict?

Comment: The name of the dataframe is "movies". There is a column called "title". I created a column called "year" by copying the "title" column, and now I want to edit the "year" column by doing exactly what you suggested (I simplified in my question but maybe this is the cause of my failures??)

Comment: Maybe. Try to do the same as in example in terms of names and code, which works well.

Comment: I realised that your suggestion does work after all, I'm a newbie and thank you!

Comment: Nice to hear it! Consider accepting the solution as an answer please.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the variable `i` stores a copy of data, not original reference.

So, you should do:

```
for i in range(len(df['title'])):
    if df['title'][i][-1] != ')':
        df['title'][i] = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` stores only the data, it isn't a reference to the list item.

You can do that with enumerate:

```
for index, element in enumerate(df['title']):
    if element[-1] != ')':
        df['title'][index] = ''
```